# How to wrap a custom WKInterfaceImage for SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchkit

SwiftUI does a good job of providing `WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable` However, Is there any way to create a custom view for `WKInterfaceImage`?

Here is what I tried,

```
import WatchKit
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct WatchImage: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable {
    typealias WKInterfaceObjectType = WKInterfaceImage

    func makeWKInterfaceObject(context: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentableContext<WatchImage>) -> WKInterfaceImage {
        return WKInterfaceImage()
    }

    func updateWKInterfaceObject(_ wkInterfaceObject: WKInterfaceImage, context: Context) {
        wkInterfaceObject.setImage(UIImage(named: "start"))
   }
}
```

But code is not compiling and giving an error on line `return WKInterfaceImage()` and says **init() is unavailable**

This is probably because we can not create an object of `WKInterfaceImage` programmatically. We need to use it with storyboard.

So Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Image("start")`? What's the purpose of `WKInterfaceImage` here?

Comment: I want to use the animation functionality of  `WKInterfaceImage`. I have a number of images and using that I want to display an animated image. @Asperi

Comment: @SagarUnagar did you ever find a way to do this? I have made an imaged ImageView in SwiftUI but its much less performant compared to the native animation functionality of WKInterfaceImage

Answer (score -1):

Apple says,

Do not subclass or create instances of this class yourself. Instead, define outlets in your interface controller class and connect them to the corresponding objects in your storyboard file.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfaceimage

Comment: This option is not available in SwiftUI. The WKInterfaceImage object delivers more use cases (like animation) than the SwiftUI Image