# SwiftUI - How to create a performant frame by frame animated Image View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch

## Context

I am in the process of converting an Apple Watch app from WatchKit to SwiftUI.

This app makes use of animated `WKInterfaceImage` which loop through a sequences of images in a performant way.

The app has a sequence of 16 images which are lopped through over 0.66 seconds. Images are small pngs (~8kb 256 x 256 pixels).

*A full zip of the images from the asset catalogue can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dl/dw7jyvqo8x50b31/running-images.zip).*

## Approach

To do this I created a simple `FrameAnimatedImageView` as follows:

```
struct FrameAnimatedImageView: View{
    
    let imageName: String
    let frameCount: Int
    let duration: TimeInterval

    @State private var currentFrameIndex: Int
    
    private var currentImageName: String {
        "\(imageName)\(currentFrameIndex)"
    }
    
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    
    init(imageName: String, frameCount: Int, duration: TimeInterval) {
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.frameCount = frameCount
        self.duration = duration
        
        self.currentFrameIndex = 0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(currentImageName)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .onAppear(perform: startAnimationTimer)
            .onDisappear(perform: stopAnimationTimer)
    }
    
    private func startAnimationTimer() {
        stopAnimationTimer()
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: duration / Double(frameCount), repeats: true) { (Timer) in
            currentFrameIndex = (currentFrameIndex + 1) % frameCount
        }
        RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
    }
    
    private func stopAnimationTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
    
}
```

## Issue

This gave the same result but uses significantly more CPU (around 15% on a S6 Apple Watch vs <1% `WKInterfaceImage` animation).

I did a little profiling noticed the swiftUI redrawing was the main activity followed by image loading.

Based on this I made a slight optimisation to use UImages (and the built in caching) to populate the SwiftUI Image view.

```
struct FrameAnimatedImageView: View{
    
    let imageName: String
    let frameCount: Int
    let duration: TimeInterval

    @State private var currentFrameIndex: Int
    
    private var currentImageName: String {
        "\(imageName)\(currentFrameIndex)"
    }
    
    private var currentImage: UIImage { // Slight optimisation
        UIImage(named: currentImageName)!
    }
    
    
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    
    init(imageName: String, frameCount: Int, duration: TimeInterval) {
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.frameCount = frameCount
        self.duration = duration
        
        self.currentFrameIndex = 0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: currentImage) // Slight optimisation
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .onAppear(perform: startAnimationTimer)
            .onDisappear(perform: stopAnimationTimer)
    }
    
    private func startAnimationTimer() {
        stopAnimationTimer()
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: duration / Double(frameCount), repeats: true) { (Timer) in
            currentFrameIndex = (currentFrameIndex + 1) % frameCount
        }
        RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
    }
    
    private func stopAnimationTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
    
}

@available(watchOSApplicationExtension 7.0, *)
struct FrameAnimatedImageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FrameAnimatedImageView(imageName: "running", frameCount: 16, duration: 0.66)
    }
}
```

Performance (10-15% of watch CPU used on this animated image) is still far from ideal and i'm not keen on shipping with this approach.

## Alternatives

I've tried/considered the following options:

**Use WKImageView by wrapping it in a WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable.**

This does not seem to possible as WKImageView does not expose a public init. More info: [How to wrap a custom WKInterfaceImage for SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087628/how-to-wrap-a-custom-wkinterfaceimage-for-swiftui)

**Use SwiftUI Canvas to draw the image**

Rather than using a SwiftUi Image use the SwiftUI Canvas and draw the image. From a quick attempt this did not seem to reduce cpu usage (it actually made it slightly worse).

**Create a UIImage animatedImage and pass that to Swift Image**

Use the built in [animation support on UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624149-animatedimage) to just have one UIImage object which is then passed to the SwiftUI Image view. This does not work and SwiftUI just draws the first frame.

**Anything else?**

I'm not sure if there is a better approach to this?

Comment: Try switching to TimelineView instead of Timer

Comment: @loremipsum I have just tried using TimelineView and performance is very similar to the Timer based approach. Code is probably slightly cleaner but performance wise it's roughly the same.

Comment: Have you tried rendering this with a `drawingGroup` modifier? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/enabling-high-performance-metal-rendering-with-drawinggroup

Comment: PNGs are expensive - can you go JPEG? Also, if using UIImages, you can lazily `prepareForDisplay()` and `prepareThumbnail` to reduce the memory overhead from rendering, so there's less work to be done at display-time.

Comment: @OscarApeland I can change the image format if is helps. These are very small pngs with only a few colours in so ideal for the png format. Jpeg is likely to have artifacts and could result in larger file sizes. 

Are you aware of any articles that show the performance of different image formats when used in Image?

Comment: @BriannaDoubt I just tried this and it didn't help. I imagine it is only useful if rendering structs of views. In my case I'm just rendering a single view which is already an image.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could put all of your frames into a single image as a horizontal or vertical strip, and then animate by moving the view across the strip.

Answer (score -2):

For better performance I'm afraid you'll have to wrap UIKit. Give this a shot:

```
struct FrameAnimatedImageView: View {

    let imageName: String
    let duration: TimeInterval

    var body: some View {
        AnimatedImageView(name: imageName, duration: duration)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}

struct AnimatedImageView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let name: String
    let duration: TimeInterval

    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.image = .animatedImageNamed(name, duration: duration)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AnimatedImageView>) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This won’t work on watchOS

Comment: Yeah sadly this isnt an option on WatchOS.